# About Kafka producer error handler stagey

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm hesitating that should I use Kafka producer Async or Sync API, I prefer ASync API, but when there is an exception, it's hard to catch it up. I wrote a CallBack Function to remember the failed messages, and then save them to database.

If I used Sync API, I have to design some Exception Classes to catch some specific Exceptions and use suitable failure handler logic.

So from failure handle perspective, which API should I use, Sync or Async?

Answer (score 2):

According to me you should use Kafka Producer ASYNC API and should try to publish that message again in case of any error.

Comment: hi Abhimanyu, thank you so much! We decided to use Sync producer API. Do you have idea that how can I handle exceptions when I producer a list messages rather a single message. How can i notice the upper stream API, when the list writing failed.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason for using sync. As while using sync api your producer will be slow.

Comment: Sync API is easier to control the exceptions and transaction. I planed to use Transaction to solve the question which I asked you a day a ago. Thanks :)

Comment: @Abhimanyu I am still looking for a way to handle exceptions on async and perform retry for the message. I am not able to get the message and header to retry. If you have some information. Please let me know. It would be great help

Comment: @AshishGupta you can capture below exceptions using onCompletion method at time of implementing Callback interface .Please refere to this document for more details https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html